# limit stockfish 9 to a specific range of ELO rating

Tags: engines, stockfish, elo

I am using stockfish 9 for our chess game project, and I want to limit the ELO rating of the engine to a range. I saw attributes like `movetime` and `depth` are used to limit the engine skill level, but I am not sure about how to match these attributes to a specific ELO rating.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish. Check `UCI_LimitStrength`. One of the UCI options.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For the skill level options, do you mean the ```depth``` attribute?

Comment: No the options include a skill level attribute from 1 to 20

Comment: could you provide a link for the document?

Comment: https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish. Read it please.

Comment: Sorry... I just read it. The document just explains what the option is, and it doesn't explain how to use it. Do you know how to use the skill level option? I mean I want to change the skill level through code.